# How can we set the CommandTimeout as a property in our class and when set it will take effect all in DAL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sqlcommand

How can we set the CommandTimeout as a property in our class and when set it will take effect all in DAL

```
using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
{
  command.CommandTimeout = 60; //I need to make this globally. so all my timeout will have a 60 second
}
```

I also did this but no luck

```
public class Test : IDbCommand
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        CommandTimeout = 10;

    using (var sqlcon = new SqlConnection("Server=Server2;Database=;Trusted_Connection=true"))
    {
        using (var sqlcom =  sqlcon.CreateCommand())
        {

        }
    }
}
int _cto;
public int CommandTimeout
{
    get
    {
        return _cto;
    }
    set
    {
        _cto = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a method from where SqlCommand object will be returned and you can use it in every method so every command will have timeout 60;

```
public SqlCommand GetCommandObj()
{
        SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandTimeout=60;
        cmd.CommandText="your query here";
        return cmd;
}
```

You can also set other properties for command object;

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest solution is to create a single class e.g. *CommandFactory* which will be only responsible for creating commands and which will be used globbaly in the whole application. This of course will require some amount of refactoring of your source code but it doesn't seem to be very complicated. *CommandFactory* should create commands objects according to some rules. In your case it will set *CommandTimeout* property to 60 but it can also set other properties. The value of timeout can be hardcoded but the better way is to read it from a configuration. Here is a very basic example:

```
public static class CommandFactory
{
    public static DbCommand CreateCommnad(DbConnection connection)
    {
        var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandTimeout = ReadTimeoutFromConfig();
        //Set other properites to default values
        return cmd;
    }
}


...
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Server=Server2;Database=;Trusted_Connection=true"))
{
    using (var command = CommandFactory.CreateCommnad(connection))
    {
        command.CommandText = "...";
        //Execute a command, read results etc.
    }
}
...
```